# How to calculate probability of a letter in a string

Tags: c++, string, probability

So I'm working on a project in (C++) in which I have to calculate the probability of a nucleotide in a DNA sequence/s that has been read from a text file. I have already figured out other information about the file such as the mean length of the sequences, variance,  deviation etc.

example... 
`"atgatatgagc"`

I could give a likely hood of an `'a'` popping up or a `'t`' .. etc

any tips or suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide more information here.

Comment: Are you looking for the 'frequency' of the nucleotide? How many times it is used in the sequence relative to the size of the sequence? I suspect that you will do better to look at bio-informatics libraries, unless this is homework...

Comment: Are you asking how to make a std::map<char, int> histogram of values in a std::string ?

Comment: Is this something more complicated than counting the number of times each character appears and dividing by the total number of characters?

Answer (score 4):

```
char letter='a';
string str="abcd"; 
cout << (double) std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), letter) / str.size();
```

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of more information, and assuming equal probabilities for each letter, then the probability for any letter "popping up" is 1/4, assuming four possible letters, `A`, `T`, `G` and `C`.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of Leonid Volnitsky code :

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std ;



int main(void)
{

    char character_A='A';
    char character_C='C';
    char character_G='G';
    char character_T='T';

    string DNA_Sequence="ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGCCTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGGAAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCCCTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAGTTTAATTACAGACCTGAA"; 

    int occurrences_A=std::count(DNA_Sequence.begin(), DNA_Sequence.end(), character_A);
    double probability_A =(double) occurrences_A/ DNA_Sequence.size();

    int occurrences_C=std::count(DNA_Sequence.begin(), DNA_Sequence.end(), character_C);
    double probability_C =(double) occurrences_C/ DNA_Sequence.size();

    int occurrences_G=std::count(DNA_Sequence.begin(), DNA_Sequence.end(), character_G);
    double probability_G =(double) occurrences_G/ DNA_Sequence.size();

    int occurrences_T=std::count(DNA_Sequence.begin(), DNA_Sequence.end(), character_T);
    double probability_T =(double) occurrences_T/ DNA_Sequence.size();


    cout<<"In the DNA sequence  \n\n["<<DNA_Sequence <<"]    \n\n\n" ;
    cout<<"The probability of ["<<character_A <<"] in the sequence   = "<<probability_A <<"  ("<<probability_A*100 <<"%)  ("<<occurrences_A<<" A's)  \n" ;
    cout<<"The probability of ["<<character_C <<"] in the sequence   = "<<probability_C <<"  ("<<probability_C*100 <<"%)  ("<<occurrences_C<<" C's)  \n" ;
    cout<<"The probability of ["<<character_G <<"] in the sequence   = "<<probability_G <<"  ("<<probability_G*100 <<"%)  ("<<occurrences_G<<" G's)  \n" ;
    cout<<"The probability of ["<<character_T <<"] in the sequence   = "<<probability_T <<"  ("<<probability_T*100 <<"%)  ("<<occurrences_T<<" T's)  \n\n" ;

    cout<<"Cross check : "<<(probability_A*100)<<"% + "<<( probability_C*100)<<"% + "<<( probability_G*100)<<"% + "<<( probability_T*100)<<
        "% = "<< (probability_A*100) + ( probability_C*100) + ( probability_G*100) + ( probability_T*100) <<"% \n";
    cout<<"Sequence size = "<<DNA_Sequence.size()<<"  (A + C + G + T = "<<occurrences_A+occurrences_C+occurrences_G+occurrences_T<<") \n\n";


    cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";

    cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
In the DNA sequence

[ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGG
TGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGCCTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTT
GGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGGAAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAA
GGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCCCTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAA
ATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAGTTTAATTACAGACCTGAA]


The probability of [A] in the sequence   = 0.214674  (21.4674%)  (79 A's)
The probability of [C] in the sequence   = 0.334239  (33.4239%)  (123 C's)
The probability of [G] in the sequence   = 0.285326  (28.5326%)  (105 G's)
The probability of [T] in the sequence   = 0.165761  (16.5761%)  (61 T's)

Cross check : 21.4674% + 33.4239% + 28.5326% + 16.5761% = 100%
Sequence size = 368  (A + C + G + T = 368)


Press any key to continue
```